# How to remove 'data' array key in Json response

Tags: json, laravel

I'm new in Laravel 7 and now my problem is the JSON response data wrapped by the `data` array key.

Response data

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3017,
            "total": "87.98",
            "subtotal": 83,
            "total_tax_items": 4.98,
            "count_items": 3,
        }
     ]
}
```

Expected response data

```
  {
    {
        "id": 3017,
        "total": "87.98",
        "subtotal": 83,
        "total_tax_items": 4.98,
        "count_items": 3,
    }
 }
```

Here is my code that returns from the eloquent collection.

```
$query = Sale::with(['items'])
                    ->select('id', 'total')
                    ->get();

return json_resp($query);
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the laravel function json_resp(), is that something you have written yourself?

Comment: try `dd($query)` and check result

Answer (score 0):

try return as:
  `return response()->json($result);`